# while infinite loop after 2 loops

Tags: python

I basically want to put each letter to a different list so that the first letter goes in the first list until the `kth` letter. Then the `k+1th` letter should go in the `k-1th` list and the next to the `k-2th` list etc. The fact is that after the second loop the while enters in an infinite loop

```
def f(s,k):      
 l = [[] for i in range(k)]
 i = 0
 while i < len(s):
   for j in range(0,k):
     l[j].append(s[i])
     print(l)
     i += 1
   for k in range(k-2,-1,-1):
     l[k].append(s[i])
     print(l)
     i += 1
 return l
```

Comment: how do you call it, i.e. what arguments you pass to it? currently it's not very clear what the function is really meant to do, also what's the expected output?

Comment: I don't see any reason for an infinite loop. But you'll get an error when `i` goes outside the length of `s`, unless `len(s)` is a multiple of `(k + k - 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the same variable `k` for the second iteration variable and your function parameter. When the second loop is done, `k` will be set to `0`. The next iteration of the `while` loop will then do `for j in range(0, 0):`, which doesn't do anything, followed by `for k in range(-2, -1, -1):`, which also doesn't do anything. So `i` never gets incremented any more, and you get stuck in the infinite loop.

Change `for k` to `for m` and you won't get the infinite loop. But you'll get an `IndexError` when accessing `s[i]` if `len(s)` is not a multiple of `2 * k - 1`.

It would be better to iterate over the characters in `s`.

```
def f(s,k):      
    l = [[] for i in range(k)]
    i = 0
    inc = 1
    for c in s:
        l[i].append(c)
        i += inc
        # Check if we need to reverse direction
        if inc == 1 and i == k:
            inc = -1
            i = k - 2
        elif inc == -1 and i == -1:
            inc = 1
            i = 0
    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73128426/11777562) already stated, the reason why your algorithm does not work are the `for`-loops. So you effectively skip the first letter, at least.
Also the usage of `k` is problematic.
However his proposed algorithm doesn't work like you want it to work, though.
In the end this is what [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73128426/11777562) had in mind:

```py
def f(string, k):
    result = [[] for _ in range(k)]
    bin_index = -1
    inc = 1
    for i in range(len(string)):
        bin_index += inc
        # reverse by setting the bin_index and changing the increment-step
        if bin_index == k:
            bin_index = (k - 1) - 1
            inc = -1
        # going forward again
        if bin_index == 0 and i != 0:
            inc = 1
        result[bin_index].append(string[i])

    return result
```

---

[@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73128426/11777562):
You have a bug in your program when `i` returns from the back-pass. It will not be set to another bin-index so that always the character on index `k+1` and `k+2` (or multiples of them) will be in the same bin (the first list). But they should be in two different bins. So this would get rid of the bug:

```py
def f(s, k):
    l = [[] for i in range(k)]
    i = 0
    inc = 1
    for c in s:
        l[i].append(c)
        i += inc
        # Check if we need to reverse direction
        if inc == 1 and i == k:
            inc = -1
            i = k - 2
        elif inc == -1 and i == -1:
            inc = 1
            i = 1 # this should be 1 not 0
    return l
```